# Why is there an error with onclick function?

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

I'm working on an assignment that asks us to use Promise, and when I run the script, I am getting this error on line 37:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

I can't understand why the onclick is throwing this error, because I have used buttons before with similar functionality, and never had an issue.  Code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Wanna See A Picture?</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <form action"/setup" method="post" id="setup">
                <h1>Enter your random image size</h1>
                <p>Enter an image width and height by entering a number between 200 and 1200 in each field.</p>
                <p>Click "Get Your Pic!" when ready.</p>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="width">Enter a width:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="width" name="width" />             
                </div>
                
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="height">Enter a height:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="height" name="height" />
                </div>
                
                <div class="field">
                    <button type="submit">Get Your Pic!</button>
                </div>
                
            </form>
        </div>
        
        <div id="imgOutput"></div>
        
        <script>
            const SUBMITBTN = document.getElementById('submit');
            
            let source = "";
            
            SUBMITBTN.onclick = function(){
                let imgWidth = document.getElementById('width');
                let imgHeight = document.getElementById('height');
                let source = `https://picsum.photos/${imgWidth}/${imgHeight}/?random`; //for grayscale add ?grayscale at end of url
            }
            
            
            let img = null;
            let imgPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            img = new Image();
            img.addEventListener('load', resolve(img));
            img.addEventListener('error', reject('Could not load image'));
            img.src = source;
            });
            
            imgPromise.then(function(fromResolve){
                let node = document.getElementById('imgOutput');
                node.appendChild(img);
            }).catch(function(fromReject){
                document.getElementById('imgOutput').innerHTML = fromReject
            });
        
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You do not have any button with id='submit' in your HTML!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const SUBMITBTN = document.getElementById('submit')
```

Null was returned because you used `getElementById` and there are no ID assigned to the button. Try:

```
<button id="submit" type="submit">Get Your Pic!</button>
```

Note:

Hard-assigning id to the button may not be ideal if there are multiple submit buttons. Potentially look for a more descriptive name and find a [query-selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) that suits your needs.

Comment: Thank you.  I figured it was something stupid.  I just couldn't see it.  Appreciate the help!